# The infinite loop to make the connection with opcua server, regardless of disconnecting the client

Tags: threadpool, opc-ua, milo

If the certificates are wrong that I put in the OpcUaClientConfigBuilder then the error comes inifinitly which makes the traffic on the opcua server.

After some time the number of connections are that huge that the data is not coming for the client that is successfully connected due to the traffic in the server.

The error is:

````
Failed to connect to OPC UA server.
2024-03-15 16:03:51.467  INFO 2300133 --- [nio-9002-exec-3] com.neos.opcua.service.OpcuaService      : Failed to connect to OPCUA server 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to connect to OPC UA server.
2024-03-15 16:03:51.467  INFO 2300133 --- [nio-9002-exec-3] com.neos.opcua.service.OpcuaService      : Close connection
2024-03-15 16:03:51.467  INFO 2300133 --- [nio-9002-exec-3] com.neos.opcua.service.OpcuaService      : client org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk.client.OpcUaClient@469472c4
2024-03-15 16:03:51.467  INFO 2300133 --- [nio-9002-exec-3] com.neos.opcua.Handler.OpcuaHandler      : Client is disconnected.
2024-03-15 16:03:52.480 ERROR 2300133 --- [ty-event-loop-8] m.o.s.c.t.u.UascClientAcknowledgeHandler : [remote=/ip:port] Received error message: ErrorMessage{error=StatusCode{name=Bad_SecurityChecksFailed, value=0x80130000, quality=bad}, reason=[BadSecurityChecksFailed]}
2024-03-15 16:03:54.497 ERROR 2300133 --- [ty-event-loop-9] m.o.s.c.t.u.UascClientAcknowledgeHandler : [remote=/ip:port] Received error message: ErrorMessage{error=StatusCode{name=Bad_SecurityChecksFailed, value=0x80130000, quality=bad}, reason=[BadSecurityChecksFailed]}
2024-03-15 16:03:58.512 ERROR 2300133 --- [y-event-loop-10] m.o.s.c.t.u.UascClientAcknowledgeHandler : [remote=ip:port] Received error message: ErrorMessage{error=StatusCode{name=Bad_SecurityChecksFailed, value=0x80130000, quality=bad}, reason=[BadSecurityChecksFailed]}
2024-03-15 16:04:06.528 ERROR 2300133 --- [y-event-loop-11] m.o.s.c.t.u.UascClientAcknowledgeHandler : [remote=/ip:port] Received error message: ErrorMessage{error=StatusCode{name=Bad_SecurityChecksFailed, value=0x80130000, quality=bad}, reason=[BadSecurityChecksFailed]}
2024-03-15 16:04:22.543 ERROR 2300133 --- [y-event-loop-12] m.o.s.c.t.u.UascClientAcknowledgeHandler : [remote=/ip:port] Received error message: ErrorMessage{error=StatusCode{name=Bad_SecurityChecksFailed, value=0x80130000, quality=bad}, reason=[BadSecurityChecksFailed]}
2024-03-15 16:04:38.567 ERROR 2300133 --- [y-event-loop-13] m.o.s.c.t.u.UascClientAcknowledgeHandler : [remote=/ip:port] Received error message: ErrorMessage{error=StatusCode{name=Bad_SecurityChecksFailed, value=0x80130000, quality=bad}, reason=[BadSecurityChecksFailed]}
2024-03-15 16:04:54.582 ERROR 2300133 --- [y-event-loop-14] m.o.s.c.t.u.UascClientAcknowledgeHandler : [remote=/ip:port] Received error message: ErrorMessage{error=StatusCode{name=Bad_SecurityChecksFailed, value=0x80130000, quality=bad}, reason=[BadSecurityChecksFailed]}
2024-03-15 16:05:10.599 ERROR 2300133 --- [y-event-loop-15] m.o.s.c.t.u.UascClientAcknowledgeHandler : [remote=/ip:port] Received error message: ErrorMessage{error=StatusCode{name=Bad_SecurityChecksFailed, value=0x80130000, quality=bad}, reason=[BadSecurityChecksFailed]}
2024-03-15 16:05:26.613 ERROR 2300133 --- [ty-event-loop-0] m.o.s.c.t.u.UascClientAcknowledgeHandler : [remote=/ip:port] Received error message: ErrorMessage{error=StatusCode{name=Bad_SecurityChecksFailed, value=0x80130000, quality=bad}, reason=[BadSecurityChecksFailed]}
2024-03-15 16:05:42.647 ERROR 2300133 --- [ty-event-loop-1] m.o.s.c.t.u.UascClientAcknowledgeHandler : [remote=/ip:port] Received error message: ErrorMessage{error=StatusCode{name=Bad_SecurityChecksFailed, value=0x80130000, quality=bad}, reason=[BadSecurityChecksFailed]}
2024-03-15 16:05:58.661 ERROR 2300133 --- [ty-event-loop-2] m.o.s.c.t.u.UascClientAcknowledgeHandler : [remote=/ip:port] Received error message: ErrorMessage{error=StatusCode{name=Bad_SecurityChecksFailed, value=0x80130000, quality=bad}, reason=[BadSecurityChecksFailed]}
2024-03-15 16:06:14.676 ERROR 2300133 --- [ty-event-loop-3] m.o.s.c.t.u.UascClientAcknowledgeHandler : [remote=/ip:port] Received error message: ErrorMessage{error=StatusCode{name=Bad_SecurityChecksFailed, value=0x80130000, quality=bad}, reason=[BadSecurityChecksFailed]}
2024-03-15 16:06:30.689 ERROR 2300133 --- [ty-event-loop-4] m.o.s.c.t.u.UascClientAcknowledgeHandler : [remote=/ip:port] Received error message: ErrorMessage{error=StatusCode{name=Bad_SecurityChecksFailed, value=0x80130000, quality=bad}, reason=[BadSecurityChecksFailed]}
2024-03-15 16:06:46.703 ERROR 2300133 --- [ty-event-loop-5] m.o.s.c.t.u.UascClientAcknowledgeHandler : [remote=/ip:port] Received error message: ErrorMessage{error=StatusCode{name=Bad_SecurityChecksFailed, value=0x80130000, quality=bad}, reason=[BadSecurityChecksFailed]}```

For reference my code is this
````

private static CompletableFuture createClient(String host, Integer port, String username,
String password, String certPath, String keyPath, String applicationUri, String securityPolicy) {
// create URL
String url = String.format("opc.tcp://%s:%s", host, port);

```
    return DiscoveryClient.getEndpoints(url).thenCompose(endpoints -> {
        try {
            // fetch EndpointDescription
            EndpointDescription endpointDescription = findBest(endpoints);
            MessageSecurityMode messageSecurityMode = endpointDescription.getSecurityMode();
            // set security policy
            String securityPolicyUri = endpointDescription.getSecurityPolicyUri();
            UserTokenPolicy[] userTokenPolicies = endpointDescription.getUserIdentityTokens();
            if (securityPolicy != null) {
                securityPolicyUri = "http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SecurityPolicy#" + securityPolicy;
                for (int i = 0; i < userTokenPolicies.length; i++) {
                    UserTokenPolicy userTokenPolicy = userTokenPolicies[i];
                    userTokenPolicies[i] = new UserTokenPolicy(userTokenPolicy.getPolicyId(),
                            userTokenPolicy.getTokenType(), userTokenPolicy.getIssuedTokenType(),
                            userTokenPolicy.getIssuerEndpointUrl(), securityPolicyUri);
                }
            }

            // recreate EndpointDescription as returned EndpointDescription from server might not match the specifications
            EndpointDescription endpointDescriptionModified = new EndpointDescription(url,
                    endpointDescription.getServer(), endpointDescription.getServerCertificate(),
                    MessageSecurityMode.SignAndEncrypt, securityPolicyUri, userTokenPolicies,
                    endpointDescription.getTransportProfileUri(), endpointDescription.getSecurityLevel());

            // create OpcUaClientConfigBuilder
            OpcUaClientConfigBuilder cfg = new OpcUaClientConfigBuilder();

            // set end point
            cfg.setEndpoint(endpointDescriptionModified);

            // set user name and password
            if (username != null & (certPath == null || keyPath == null)) {
                cfg.setIdentityProvider(new UsernameProvider(username, password));
            }

            // set certificates
            if (certPath != null && keyPath != null) {
                X509IdentityProvider x509IdentityProvider = new X509IdentityProvider(certPath, keyPath);
                X509Certificate cert = x509IdentityProvider.getCertificate();
                KeyPair keyPair = new KeyPair(cert.getPublicKey(), x509IdentityProvider.getPrivateKey());
                if (username != null) {
                    cfg.setCertificate(cert).setKeyPair(keyPair).setIdentityProvider(x509IdentityProvider)
                            .setIdentityProvider(new UsernameProvider(username, password));
                } else {
                    cfg.setCertificate(cert).setKeyPair(keyPair).setIdentityProvider(x509IdentityProvider);
                }
            }

            // set ApplicationUri
            if (applicationUri != null) {
                cfg.setApplicationUri(applicationUri);
            }
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(OpcUaClient.create(cfg.build()));
        } catch (final UaException e) {
            CompletableFuture<OpcUaClient> failedFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
            failedFuture.completeExceptionally(e);
            return failedFuture;
        }
    });
}
```

```
I am expecting if there is some property or something so that I can limit the retry of the connection the server. if OpcUaClientConfigBuilder has some properties. I explored the possible methods of that builder but unable to tackle that error.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client will automatically attempt to reconnect until you call `disconnect()`.

It backs off its attempts exponentially until it's attempting every ~16 seconds. This is not configurable.

> After some time the number of connections are that huge that the data is not coming for the client that is successfully connected due to the traffic in the server.

I have no idea what you're trying to say here. If you're implying that these reasonably spaced repeat connection attempts somehow crash or cause a denial-of-service in that the server, then you need to contact the vendor of that server for support, because it's broken.

Comment: I have disconnect the client successfully but still I see that the shared event loop threads created by the NioEventLoopGroup are not terminated. The event loop group is created by the sharedEventLoop() method of the org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.Stack class. In the Error logs above.

Comment: After disconnecting the client I have used Stack.releaseSharedResources(). Is there any way to know that all resources has been released. When I try to reconnect to the opcua server It shows error like

Comment: ERROR 2381036 --- [nio-9002-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.neos.opcua.exception.OpcuaException: Failed to close connection 
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task com.digitalpetri.strictmachine.StrictMachine$PollAndEvaluate@7290897 rejected from org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.Stack$3@422b8eb6[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 117]] with root cause

Comment: You should only call `Stack.releaseSharedResources` when your application shuts down and won't use Milo any more.

Comment: My application is still running. If I don't use Stack.releaseSharedResources then how I am able to restrict the thread response from server. Eg my certificate info is wrong the client tries to make connection with opcua server, it showing BadSecurityCheckFailed. but a netty nio thread loop is running continuously after I call disconnect() on the client as mentioned in  the ques ERROR logs.

Comment: It is resolved. I have maintain a global variable which assign client on creation and when completable future of Opcua Client faces an error then I disconnect() the client. Earlier I assign the client like OpcuaClient client = CompletableFuture<OpcuaClient>(some Method). If that future has some issue connecting to server, it retries infinitely and since I haven' t assign the client yet , it shows client as null. Thanks again @KevinHerron